# How to create and execute a SQL query in CSCART?

Tags: php, mysql, cs-cart

Just want to ask how can I create a simple query using CSCART?

I have this query in my code but it doesn't display my query result. Here's my code:

```
$company_list = db_query('SELECT company FROM cscart_companies ORDER BY company LIMIT 100');

fn_print_r($company_list);

foreach($company_list as $t){
    echo $t['company'];
}
```

But it only display the value from my print_r() which is:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 100
    [type] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use

```
$company_list = db_get_array('SELECT company FROM ?:companies ORDER BY company LIMIT 100');
foreach($company_list as $t){
    echo $t['company'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this works:

```
$company_list = db_get_array('SELECT company FROM ?:companies ORDER BY company LIMIT 100');
foreach ($company_list as $t){
   foreach ($t as $r) {
     echo $r['company'];
   }
}
```